# Export layer to png file in gimp

Tags: gimp

Is there a simple way to export the current selected layer as a png/jpg file in Gimp 2.8.4 ?

I did some searching in google, and the export should do it in gimp 2.6 if the layer is the only visible layer, but I can't get that to work for gimp 2.8

The way I currently do it now is that I select the content, and cut/paste it to a new image, then export the image and close it, but a simple export selected layer would be much more easy to use.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux. (Fedora but how does that matter?)

Comment: You never know, there are often differences in the same software between OSs.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485917/gimp-export-every-layer-as-a-separate-png-image

Answer (score 36):

1. select layer
2. press ctrl+c
3. press ctrl+shift+v (=paste as new image)
4. export as whatever you like

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Easy, simple, without downsides. Okay, this should be possible with GIMP, it's such a basic functionality.

Comment: This is the best answer way simpler and faster than any here. No plugins, no downloads, no lies about making a layer invisible and exporting the image as if it was a layer. This is the way we can export just the layer. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent and fast solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

I can do this on GIMP 2.8.2 running on Linux. The image below has two layers, one blue and one black.

[image]

If I export the image as is, I get a blue png. Now, set the blue layer to invisible:

[image]

If I now export this image (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) I get a nice black .png:

[image]

Comment: That works except for 2 things. The result image when exported as png still has the same size as the original image. So try to make your black box smaller and then export it. You will end up with a small black box, with a large transparent area around it.

Comment: @MTilsted If I understand your issue correctly you can go to Image > fit canvas to layer to have the image without the transparent area around it.

Comment: Your images are missing

Comment: @HQtunes.com no they aren't, not for me anyway. Perhaps you are blocking https://i.stack.imgur.com?

Comment: @terdon, no I have not blocked. But the link also broken in my pc..

Comment: @HQtunes.com well something must be blocking it. Maybe it's blocked in your country? There's nothing special about the images here, they're hosted on imgur like any other image uploaded to Stack Exchange. I can see them from both computer and phone and so can other users I asked in chat. I am afraid this isn't something I can fix.

Comment: @terdon okey I have learned that it is blocked in our country

Comment: @tubefavorites.com wow. Do you mind if I ask why is it blocked in your country? Which country are you living?

Answer (score 5):

There is a GIMP plugin to export as layers: [Export layers plugin](https://khalim19.github.io/gimp-plugin-export-layers/)

This plugin does not have the option of exporting only the current active layer - however it uses square brackets in the layer names to determine how it treats the layers.

Thus to export your current layer you could:

1. Install this plugin (you will have to restart GIMP)
2. Rename the layer or layers you wish to export, surrounding their names with square brackets e.g. [my image]
3. Select "Export layers" from the file menu
4. Enter the extension for the format you want to use in the extension field
5. Under advanced settings change the "layer names in [square brackets]:" option to "Ignore other layers"
6. Click export layers

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485917/gimp-export-every-layer-as-a-separate-png-image

Answer (score 2):

I hit upon a simple workaround under windows:
I select the layer that I want to copy in the GIMP, press control+C to have it in the Windows clipboard. Then I open Irfan View as a separate application and I paste in the contents of the Windows clipboard with control+V. Then the pasted image can be saved to disk in whatever format I like.

Comment: That works as easily by pasting into a GIMP window with a new image

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "Save As" operation ignores layers and visibility in
formats where layers are not supported. Merging or flattening the image
for export is a separate operation available before Gimp converts the
format, and it is not mandatory. You can skip the flattening and
merging operation by clicking "Ignore." 

When you chose to "Save As" from the file menu, by default only the
active layer is exported unless the target format supports layers. For
example, if your image has three layers and you want a PNG image, the
PNG will only have graphic information for one layer: the active layer,
UNLESS you flatten the image or merge layers.

Now to save three layers as three images, you need to make three "save
as" operations. The steps below outline the sequence for creating separate images from layers.

1. Ensure the editor window is active with the top layer selected.
2. Press "CTRL-SHIFT-S" for the Save As dialogue.
3. Choose your output format, and file name for the FIRST page. Press "Enter"
4. On the Export dialogue, choose "Ignore"
5. Set the options for your destination format and press "Enter" or
   click "Save."

   You are now returned to the image editor window. Repeat the below steps
   for each layer.
6. Press "Page Down" to activate the next layer.
7. Press "CTRL-SHIFT-S" for the Save As dialogue.
8. Choose your output format, and file name for the NEXT page. Press "Enter"
9. On the Export dialogue, choose "Ignore"
10. The options for your destination format are remembered. Press
    "Enter" or click "Save."

A Script-fu could easily handle this.
Using layer keyboard shortcuts you can export each layer in very few
steps.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

1. Shift-click on the "eye" icon of the layer you want to export: this hides all the other layers
2. Ctrl+Shift+E: this brings up the Export dialog